# Swift 2 Closure troubles

Tags: swift, imgur

SO originally I was having some trouble with Swift 2 closures, here was my problem:

```
func getImgurHotListWithViralBool(viral:Bool) -> NSArray
{
    IMGGalleryRequest.hotGalleryPage(0, withViralSort: viral,
                                     success:{
                                        (objects:NSArray)  in
//It gives the error here*********
                                     },
                                     failure: {(error:NSError) in

                                     })
}
```

It gives the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSArray) -> ()' to expected argument
>   type '(([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!'

**UPDATE:**
Thankfully, **Marco Boschi** helped me with this solution;

```
func getImgurHotListWithViralBool(viral:Bool) -> NSArray {
    IMGGalleryRequest.hotGalleryPage(0, withViralSort: viral,
        success: { (objects: [AnyObject]!)  in
            // ...
        }, failure: { (error:NSError) in
            // ...
        })
}
```

And now the error is present in `error:NSError` i.e :

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSError) -> ()' to expected argument
>   type '(([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!'

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried removing the explicit type from it? `success:{ objects in /* ... */ }`. And please post your code and the exact error message, not a screenshot of both.

Comment: Please update your question and post your code as text. It makes it much easier to read and reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're using require a closure that accept as a single argument a Swift array, an implicitly unwrapped one, of `AnyObject`s (`[AnyObject]!`) as stated in the error message, but you are using an old `NSArray` and the compiler cannot convert the type of your closure to the requested one, hence the error, changing the code as below will solve it.

```
func getImgurHotListWithViralBool(viral:Bool) -> NSArray {
    IMGGalleryRequest.hotGalleryPage(0, withViralSort: viral,
        success: { (objects: [AnyObject]!)  in
            // ...
        }, failure: { (error:NSError) in
            // ...
        })
}
```

**UPDATE:** the second error you get is the same as before, the API wants a closure that accept an implicitly unwrapped array of `AnyObject`s but you provide one that take an `NSError`, you'll have to change the signature of `failure` to

```
failure: { (error: [AnyObject]!) in
    // ...
}
```

in order to solve it. Make sure to check the documentation of your API to know how to get the error from the array.

Comment: This relatively okay, because now it gives error at "(error:NSError)".. lol :)

Comment: It probably is something like the original error, please update your question with the new one.

Comment: @cookiemonsta I've updated my answer, hope it helps you

Comment: dude, thank you for all the effort, but somehow the error thing didnt pan out, its still the same!

Comment: You should probably get another error for not retuning a `NSArray` from `getImgurHotListWithViralBool()` but that's unrelated to your closures, try double checking on the API documentation the signature of `hotGalleryPage()` to make sure Xcode is not giving some misleading information as I've seen it doing so